# Programmable SMS: Creating a Service Resource via API vs the twilio.com/console

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm enjoying the Twilio API.

Would someone be able to explain the differences between adding a Programmable SMS/Messaging Service via me logging into the twilio.com/console and creating a service resource via the API, https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/services/api#create-a-service-resource.

When I'm logged into the console and click the + to add a new messaging service I'm prompted for USE CASE, with many options: "Mixed", "Marketing, Outbound Only", ...
but the API does not have such a parameter.

What I'd like to know is which settings are set when creating a messaging service for each of the options and what are the values of these settings. Given there are currently nine options, I'd rather not have to create nine different Messaging Services in order to discern the differences.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options in that Twilio Console drop down of the Create a New Messaging Service dialog, "Mixed", "Marketing, Outbound Only", etc have no impact on the behavior of the messaging service. They are an artifact of the GUI and can be safely ignored.